# Get the location of System.out.println

Tags: java, system.out

I have created a web project and deployed it on weblogic (admin server).
The application is working fine but I am not able to see the `System.out.println` which I had added in my classes. I am aware normally logs get generated at

`"\user_projects\domains\xyzDomain\servers\AdminServer\logs"`

But in my case the files in this folder are not getting  updated. 
Can I know the file location where `System.out.println` is being directeed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a decent operating system type:

```
lsof -p PID
```

where PID is the process id of your server. Look for file descriptor 1.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at you shell script that starts weblogic. You should find the information in there.